# Test the arguments passed to a private method

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

```
public class DAO1 {
    private SimpleJDBCall jdbccall;
    @Autowired
    public DAO1(@Qualifier("datasource") DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbccall = createJdbcCall(someparameters)
        }

    public Response fetch(parameters){ 
    jdbccall.execute(parameters);
    }
}
```

I want to test this DAO1 class, mainly if execute method is executed using certain parameters , 
any idea if that is possible ?

I know we can use argument captor for public methods, 
but SimpleJDBCall is private,

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score -1):

For every element which interaction you want to test, you should use **dependency injection**. That's a good rule for testing.

Alternatively you could think if you can test **result** of `jdbccall.execute(parameters)`, not just the arguments - that would be the best solution. What should be the state of the system after `execute` is called with correct arguments?

Assuming you are doing unit testing and you can't check result of `execute`, then you should somehow pass object of type `SimpleJDBCall` in constructor. Now there are three possibilities:

1. Create another constructor that would take both `DataSource` and `SimpleJDBCall` - then you could do something like:

   ```
   public DAO1(@Qualifier("datasource") DataSource dataSource) {
       this(dataSource, createJdbcCall(someparameters))
   }

   public DAO1(DataSource dataSource, SimpleJDBCall jdbccall) {
       this.jdbccall = jdbccall
   }
   ```
2. Modify constructor and add autowired `SimpleJDBCall` to your container (but from name jdbCall I assume that's not simple solution)
3. Modify constructor (or add another one) with object that can create `SimpleJDBCall` - it might be factory, it might be simple function:

   ```
   public DAO1(@Qualifier("datasource") DataSource dataSource, Supplier<SimpleJDBCall> jdbcCallCreator) {
       jdbccall = jdbcCallCreator.get();
   }
   ```

   or, if it requires arguments:

   ```
   public DAO1(@Qualifier("datasource") DataSource dataSource, Function<ArgumentType, SimpleJDBCall> jdbcCallCreator) {
       jdbccall = jdbcCallCreator.apply(arguments);
   }
   ```

Don't be afraid to modify your class for purpose of testing - if it is not testable maybe it was not designed well in the first place?